# Random and Itertools

Tags: python, random, python-itertools

I have some sample code that iterates through two different ranges of numbers successfully, but I want to add functionality to it so that it moves through the chained ranges randomly like so:

```
import itertools
import random

for f in random.sample(itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24)), 48):

    print f
```

However this produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    for f in random.sample(itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24)), 48):
  File "G:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 321, in sample
    n = len(population)
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()
```

Can anyone advise the amendments needed to make this function as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be as follows:

```
for f in random.sample(list(itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24))), 48):
```

The problem with your code is that to sample from some iterable randomly, you need to know its length first, but `itertools.chain` is an iterable that provides only the `__iter__` method and no `__len__`.

Basically, to do `random.choice` or `random.sample` or anything that involves *choosing* elements at random, you'll need a sequence or a set, which means that sequence should be *finite*. Iterables that don't provide the `__len__` method are considered infinite as you'll never know how many elements will be produced until the iterable's exhausted, if at all.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `itertools.chain` creates generators, rather than lists. These generators are lazily evaluated, each element exists only briefly and is discarded after use.  The `len` function is not defined for generators because all the elements don't exist at once.

To fix your issue, you'll have to explicitly convert the chain output to a list.

```
c = itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24))
for f in random.sample(list(c), 48):
```

Answer (score 3):

As the [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) documentation states,

> Returns a *k* length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set

It requires a sequence or a set so that it can sample from the entire population, but [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) returns an iterator which could even be infinite. So `sample` cannot determine the actual size of the population. That is why you are getting this error.

To fix this, you can simply create a list or a tuple and pass it to `sample`, like this

```
for f in random.sample(list(itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24))), 48)
```

---

**Note:** The other problem in your code is that, the sampling quantity cannot be bigger than the actual population.

```
>>> len(range(30, 54))
24
>>> len(range(1, 24))
23
```

So the population size is 47 and you are sampling 48 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert `population` to a `list` explicitly. You can try like this:

```
n = len(list(population))
```

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you can get the length of a generator type object with the following syntax:

```
print sum(1 for x in (f for f in random.sample(list(itertools.chain(range(30, 54), range(1, 24))), 56)))
```